# TCP port based routing through nginx-ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, tcp, nginx-ingress

I am attempting to use my Kubernetes hosted nginx-ingress to do port based TCP routing.

*Note: I am only using SSH here for testing but intend to use a proprietary TCP protocol later once this has been resolved.*

Edit: Added deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
....
```

My service definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-ssh
  labels:
    app: test-ssh
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: test-ssh
      port: 2222
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 22
  selector:
    app: test
```

My tcp-configmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  "2222": default/test-ssh:2222
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-nginx-tcp
  namespace: nginx-ingress
```

From a node in the cluster I am able to connect to the service:

```
 $ kubectl  get svc  | grep test-ssh
 test-ssh     ClusterIP   10.43.18.226    <none>        2222/TCP   16m

 $ ssh 10.43.18.226 -p2222
 The authenticity of host '[10.43.18.226]:2222 ([10.43.18.226]:2222)' can't be established.
 Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? ^C
```

When applying the service I get the below log in the nginx controller logs:

```
controller.go:388] Service "default/test-ssh" does not have any active Endpoint for TCP port 2222
```

This may be a race condition as if I describe the EP post full deployment:

```
Name:         test-ssh
Namespace:    default
Labels:       app=test-ssh
Subsets:
  Addresses:          10.42.2.24
  NotReadyAddresses:  <none>
  Ports:
    Name      Port  Protocol
    ----      ----  --------
    test-ssh  22    TCP

Events:  <none>
```

If I attempt to SSH through the TCP load balancer attached to nginx I get a routing error. I would expect this to be transparently routed to the service endpoint:

```
$ ssh x.x.x.x -p2222 -v
......
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 0: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 1: Date: Sun, 04 Jul 2021 09:11:03 GMT
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 2: Content-Type: text/html
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 3: Content-Length: 150
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 4: Connection: close
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 5:
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 6: <html>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 7: <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 8: <body>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 9: <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 10: <hr><center>nginx</center>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 11: </body>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 12: </html>
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

In the nginx controller logs I get:

```
10.42.1.0 - - [04/Jul/2021:08:47:59 +0000] "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.001 [] [] - - - - ab9dec024b834c83210af117fa95571b
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Share the deployment.yaml. probably the label for pod is  not matching the lable in service.

Comment: I have updated and added the deployment in initial post for completeness. I would expect if there is a selector mismatch I would not be able to connect directly to the service within the cluster via the clusterIP.

Comment: Is the pod configured to run on port 22 in deployment.yaml

Comment: Yes its running on port 22/tcp.

Comment: Are they all in same namespace nginx-ingress.  I see configmap is in this namespace. Checm if svc and pod are in same namespace.

Comment: Yes the ssh pod and ssh service are both in the default namespace.

Comment: What is this configmap for? Bring this also in same namespace default. Then check.